# Multiple JavaScript files in Cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am writing a Cordova plugin and naturally, there is a JavaScript file (`www/js/plugin.js`) that prodivdes the interface between the Plugin and the rest of the application. Is it possible to add another JavaScript file (`www/js/plugin-helper.js`) that can then be imported into `www/js/plugin.js`?

I've tried using a second `js-module` tag in the plugin.xml file that points to the second file like this:

```
<js-module src="www/js/plugin.js" name="MyTest2">
        <clobbers target="window.plugins.mytest2" />
    </js-module>
<js-module src="www/js/plugin-helper.js" name="PluginHelper"/>
```

This did not work and resulted in the error: Uncaught module cordova-plugin-my-test2.plugin-helper not found.

Is there a way to import `www/js/plugin-helper.js` into `www/js/plugin.js`?